# How can I filter results of map-reduce in Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Is there a way to filter the results of map-reduce operation in Mongoid? I found a 'query' function that can be executed on the MongoDB but there doesn't seem to be a mapping in Mongoid.

I'd like to get activity counts for all users who have that value greater than 10:

```
Activity.map_reduce(%{
    emit(this.user_id, 1);
  }, %{
    function(key, values) {
      return Array.sum(values);
    }
  }).out(inline: true).query(:'value.gt' => 10)
```

Comment: query filters the documents before map and reduce are run - is that what you want?

Comment: No, after. I want to filter the post-reduce results - like what I tried to illustrate using the 'query' call above

Comment: is there a reason you don't just use aggregation framework - this is simple and faster in it vs. map-reduce.  What version of Mongoid are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid supports aggregation framework (as of 3.x) which makes this simple:

```
group =  { "$group" =>
             { "_id" => "$user_id", "count" => { "$sum" => 1 } } 
}

match = {"$match" => 
           { "count"    => { "$gt" => 10} }
}

Activity.aggregate([group,match])
```

Comment: Thanks! There was, in fact, no good reason not to do it. So, I didn't. I fixed your code to use $project instead of $unwind.

Comment: ok. I don't see an $unwind in my code, but I'm sure whatever you did is the right thing for your use case, I was just trying to show minimal working example :)

Comment: now that I see your "suggested" edit - you don't need $project - aggregation framework is smart enough to only bring through the pipeline the fields that it will need.  As far as using $sort and $limit - I expect those can be added "as needed".